# Wordpress wp_enqueue_style() does not work although path is ok

Tags: wordpress

I try to convert a html template to wordpress. I try to create a child theme from Twenty Nineteen =>

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Nineteen Child - Cigolo
Theme URI: http://inanccagiran.local/wp-content/themes/cigolo
Version: 1.0.0
Template: Twenty Nineteen
Text Domain: cigolo
*/
```

Then I try to get the css files in functions.php =>

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.
    $child_style = 'child-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style )
    );


}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );

function new_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentynineteen-style', 'netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css');

    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/plugins/bootstrap.min.css', array(), null, 'all'  );


}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'new_theme_enqueue_styles' );
```

Now I get `404` for `bootstrap.min.css` although path seems ok in network tab of developer tools.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Your syntax looks right. $child_style is not used anywhere and you can leave the parameters for bootstrap-css away (everything after bootstrap.min.css'), but it shouldn't matter. Can you try putting the full URL in the bootstrap-css line instead of "get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/plugins/bootstrap.min.css'" and also try downloading the file? Just to make sure it's not a naming issue (calling bootstrap.min.css but hosting bootstrap.css for example)?

Answer (score -1):

```
get_template_directory_uri();
```

returns main theme folder, for child theme folder use

```
get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
```